# DELPHI class with dynamic array has problem with SetLength()

Tags: arrays, delphi, class, dynamic

I need to create a **class** containing an **array of record objects** but trying to use SetLength raise an Access Violation errror.

Consider the following example of a tree object with fruits.

```
type
TFruit = record
  color: string;
  weight: double;
end;

type
  TObjectTree = class

  Public
  Fruits: array of TFruit;

  constructor Create;
  procedure AddFruit;
end;
```

In the implementation, when trying to resize the array of Fruit objects or initializing to nil generates problems.

```
constructor TObjectTree.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;
    Fruits:=nil;              //Raises an error
end;


procedure TObjectTree.AddFruit(FruitColor: string; FruitWeight: integer);
begin
    SetLength(Fruits, Length(Fruits)+1);  //Raises an error (when I comment Fruits:=nil; in the constructor)

    Fruits[Length(Fruits)].color:=FruitColor;      
    Fruits[Length(Fruits)].weight:=FruitWeight;
end;
```

How can I use dynamic arrays in a class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something tells me you've neglected to create an instance of `TObjectTree`. You've declared a `TObjectTree` variable, but you've either not called `TObjectTree.Create`, or you've called it directly on the variable you declared instead of assigning a new value to that variable:

```
var
  Tree: TObjectTree;
begin
  // This is wrong.
  Tree.Create;

  // This is right.
  Tree := TObjectTree.Create;
```

Without properly instantiating `TObjectTree`, there is no valid memory to back the `Fruits` field you attempt to use, so assigning a value to it gives an error.

Comment: +1 this more likely to explain goings on than my memory corruption explanation

Comment: Absolutely right. This was causing the memory problems. Now it is possible to instantiate a TreeObject and set the Fruits array to nil (to evantually clear the added fruits later on by calling a class method to be implementd).

Comment: it's pointless to set Fruits to nil in the constructor. It is already nil.

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
Fruits[Length(Fruits)].color:=FruitColor;      
Fruits[Length(Fruits)].weight:=FruitWeight;
```

with

```
Fruits[High(Fruits)].color:=FruitColor;
Fruits[High(Fruits)].weight:=FruitWeight;
```

then it works.

Comment: The explanation is that dynamic arrays are 0 based and run to Length - 1.

Comment: Right, this is also a bug in the example.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the answers of iamjoosy and Rob Kennedy, I would code this like so:

```
procedure TObjectTree.AddFruit(FruitColor: string; FruitWeight: integer);
var
  NewCount: Integer;
begin
  NewCount := Length(Fruits)+1;
  SetLength(Fruits, NewCount);
  Fruits[NewCount-1].color := FruitColor;      
  Fruits[NewCount-1].weight := FruitWeight;
end;
```

It is clearer, in my view, to call `Length()` just once.

You do not need to assign `Fruits := nil` in the constructor since that happens automatically.  All fields are zero-initialised when an object is instantiated.  That said, `Fruits := nil` should not raise an error.  If it does it is probably a result of a memory corruption due to the out-of-bounds array accessing.

A further point to make is that enabling range checking would have resulted in an informative error that would have explained the problem.  This is much more helpful than relying on access violations.  I can't recommend range checking highly enough.

Finally, the `SetLength(..., Length(...)+1)` pattern typically leads to very inefficient memory usage and can lead to performance problems for large lists.  If you have Delphi 2009+, I would recommend using `TList<TFruit>` instead.

Comment: I usually use a function for such code, returning an integer which is the index of the newly created item, then use `result := length(Fruits); SetLength(Fruits,result+1); Fruits[result].color := FruitColor;` It does make more sense to me than those +1/-1 around, and it is sometimes handy to retrieve the newly created index for the caller, with no speed penalty. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Arnaud Agreed, although I'd just use `TList<TFruit>` which of course does exactly that.